# Query with conditional JOIN running slow

Tags: sql-server-2014, join, execution-plan, statistics, union

I have a query the first part of which looks like this -

```
With CTE AS (
select DISTINCT
A.col1,
A.col2,
.
.
.
from tableA A 
                    JOIN tableB B ON 
                    (
                    B.col3= 'X' and B.col4=A.col3 
                    OR
                    B.col3= 'Y' and B.col4=A.col4
                    OR
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    )

)
```

Now this query runs for more than 4 minutes and the execution plan showed a table spool which was data size of 600 MB and looked like this -

[image]

I changed this to conditional JOIN to UNIONs -

```
With CTE AS (
select 
    A.col1,
    A.col2,
    .
    .
    .
    from tableA A 
                    JOIN tableB B ON 
                    (
                    B.col3= 'X' and B.col4=A.col3 
                    )
    UNION
    select 
    A.col1,
    A.col2,
    .
    .
    .
    from tableA A 
                    JOIN tableB B ON 
                    (
                    B.col3= 'Y' and B.col4=A.col4
                    )
     UNION
     .
     .
     .                      

 )
```

Now the spool with the large number of rows vanished and the run time reduced to 17 seconds. However when I check the IO statistics, the logical reads are higher than the previous slower query. What could the reason be ?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that `AND` and `OR` has the same precedence and the long condition `x AND y OR z AND w OR v AND...` without round brackets has a bit different meaning than you think.

Your query can be rewritten that way:

```
FROM tableA AS A 
JOIN tableB AS B ON ( B.col3 = 'X' AND B.col4 = A.col3 )
                 OR ( B.col3 = 'Y' AND B.col4 = A.col4 )
                 OR (. . . . .)
```

Comment: I've tried this too and got the same run time and statistics(and plan) as the first query(the one with the spool with 29 million rows). And I think AND has precedence over OR.

Comment: `AND` and `OR` actually have different precedence. In absence of brackets, `AND` has higher priority. Your `ON` predicate, therefore, would work the same way with or without those brackets. That said, however, specifying the brackets makes the intent clearer, as not everyone can constantly remember the precedence rules.